# generating 10 values in python around one value

Tags: python, numpy, generator

I am trying do write a quick simulation program. As a first step, I want to take an input and do the following:

1. Use this input to find the corresponding value from the dict, say I
   got `29.0` in my example.
2. I would now like to generate 3 values to the left and 3 values to the right. Ideally the output should be `27.5, 28.0, 28.5, 29.0, 29.5, 30, 30.5`

Here is my program -- which is partially solving my problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def getids(tk):
    tk=tk.lower()
        r=map(lambda x:x/10.0,range(0,6))   
    val={'PPP':29}
    val={k.lower():v for k,v in val.items()}
    if tk in val:
        stk_price=val[tk]   
    for i in r:
        stk_price=stk_price + i
        print(stk_price)
getids('PPP')
```

The output is

```
29.0
29.1
29.3
29.6
30.0
30.5
```

Is it possible to use numpy and generate values around a number ? Appreciate any help.

Comment: where do the 10 values come into play? based on your question you only need 7

Comment: it is based on 29. where is logic to get number such as 27.5?

Comment: `map(lambda x:x/10.0,range(0,6))` steps with size 0.1. Why are you surprised that it is not stepping with size 0.5?

Comment: Your `for` loop should be inside the `if`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First a couple of notes on design:

1. Your dictionary should live outside the function, otherwise it gets recreated every time, which is fairly pointless and inefficient.
2. If you have a function to get a range, make it return the range. If you want to print the range or do something else with it, do that outside the function.

You are probably looking for either [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) or [`np.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html). For your simple application, they are essentially equivalent. This is especially true because there is no roundoff error when stepping with an increment of 0.5.

For a given `x`, say 29, you could do either of the following:

```
step = 0.5
price_range = np.arange(x - step * 3, x + step * 4, step)
```

OR

```
step = 0.5
price_range = np.linspace(x - step * 3, x + step * 3, 7)
```

Personally I find `linspace` easier to understand here, because you just give it the limits and the number of points. For `arange`, you have to remember that the stop is exclusive, so you have to add a margin to `x + step * 3`.

I would recommend rephrasing your program like this:

```
stocks = {
    'PPP': 29,
}
# Notice that this only runs once instead of once per function call now
# casefold is the more generalized unicode version of lower
stocks = {key.casefold: value for key, value in stocks}

def getids(tk, margin=3, step=0.5):
    tk = tk.casefold()
    if tk in val:
        price = val[tk]
        return np.linspace(price - margin * step,
                           price + margin * step, 2 * margin + 1)
    return []

print(getids('PPP'))
```

If you want the *exact* output you had before, just join the elements with newlines:

```
print('\n'.join(map(str, getids('PPP'))))
```

or equivalently,

```
print('\n'.join(str(x) for x in getids('PPP')))
```

Comment: Nice.Only problem here is that I am using python 2.7 and casefold() is available start python 3. Otherwise, worked just fine.

Comment: @Judi. Glad it worked out for you. `lower` is fine if you are using Py2. Please select one of the answers here by clicking on the check mark under the score to get your question out of the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `arange` function of numpy.

Minimal example:

```
import numpy as np

num = 29    
np.arange(num-1.5, num+2, 0.5) # (start, stop, step)
```

The output will be

```
array([ 27.5,  28. ,  28.5,  29. ,  29.5,  30. ,  30.5])
```

Comment: neat. did not know numpy has a range()-like  that works with floats.

Answer (score 3):

Very similar to `np. arange`, with `np.linspace`, you can get an array of evenly spaced values, of whatever length you want. So, in your case, to get 3 values on the left and 3 values to the right (+1 to include your actual value), you'll want a total of 7 values. You can get them like this:

```
import numpy as np

x = 29
np.linspace(x-1.5, x+1.5, 7) #start, stop, number of values

# array([ 27.5,  28. ,  28.5,  29. ,  29.5,  30. ,  30.5])
```

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: Not a numpy solution, but plain old python.

You can generate them using a combination of range / delta and steps around a piveau value:

```
def getSeries(piv, nums, delta):
    """Yields [piv + (-nums * delta):piv + nums * delta] in steps of delta"""
    for k in range(-nums,nums+1):
       yield piv + k*delta

for n in getSeries(29,3,0.5):
    print(f'{n:.1f}')
```

Output:

```
27.5  # -3
28.0  # -2
28.5  # -1
29.0  # piveau
29.5  #  1
30.0  #  2
30.5  #  3
```

Comment: OP specifically asked for a numpy version, but this is fine otherwise